# Is it possible to confirm that a pattern-matching statement is exhaustive when cases can be arbitrary predicates?

Tags: type-theory, pattern-matching

An algorithm to decide pattern match coverage can be complete by computing the complement for each case. For example:

- `Nat` The primitive constructors are `0` and `suc (n : Nat)`.

  Suppose the user provides the cases `0`, `suc (suc x)`, and `suc 0`. We can refine the set of uncovered patterns by examining each case in turn:

  1. `{0, suc n} -> {suc n}` by `0`
  2. `{suc n} -> {suc 0}` by `suc (suc x)` match part of `n` and rest `0` case (inductively if deeper)
  3. `{suc 0} -> {}` by final pattern
- `A x B` For product, consider each combination

The algorithm is based on a generative approach, and for decidable propositions, interpreting as a boolean will work too, but what will happen in the case of any regular proposition?

Comment: Would it be correct to rephrase the question in your title as "Is it possible to confirm that a pattern-matching statement is exhaustive when cases can be arbitrary predicates?"?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: What system of logic do you want to use for the predicates?

Comment: Variants of dependent type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not for truly arbitrary predicates, because of undecidable and open problems.

```ocaml
let ARBITRARY_PROGRAM : string = ...

let counterexample : () =
  match n with
  | n if (eval ARBITRARY_PROGRAM n) -> ()
  (* If we can prove ARBITRARY_PROGRAM evaluates to true for all inputs, we don't
     need another case. But for an arbitrary program this is undecidable *)
  ;;
```

---

In theorem-proving languages, you can guide the type-checker to prove some match cases will never be reached, and they will permit those cases not returning anything. Essentially, **if *you* can prove that the match statement is exhaustive, you can get the compiler to accept it**. You can do this a lot of ways, but probably the most straightforward is to convert your predicate as a dependent function and guide the compiler's type resolution to compute it at compile time.

### Dependent predicate

In languages with dependent types*, matching on one constructor can cause another type to have no valid constructors. Then you can return something like `absurd instance_with_no_constructors` or `match instance_with_no_constructors with {}`, an expression which takes the impossible instance and returns an instance of an arbitrary type, which is sound because ["ex falso"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ex+falso+quodlibet).

First, we convert the predicate into a type function which can only have an instance if it's met. This conversion is straightforward: `bool` becomes `Prop`, `Set`, or `Type` (basically the type of types: instances would be `Int`, `String`, and other types), `true` becomes `⊤` (the unit type, has 1 instance) and `false` becomes `⊥` (the empty type, has 0 instances). You can be even more straightforward: every boolean predicate `is_foo` has the corresponding dependent predicate `is_foo = true`, so if you're using the predicate in actual computations, you may want to just use that. However for the purposes of this, we'll use dependent predicates directly, since the `is_foo = true` predicates have extra boilerplate.

Then, we write the pattern match, but use the compiler's type-checking as well as our own hints and lemmas to resolve the predicate. In cases where it's resolved to `⊥` (false), we use ex-falso to skip writing an actual body.

* and also GADTs, but writing predicates with those isn't so straightforward

#### [Agda](https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php) example

In Agda, we use the [absurd pattern](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/function-definitions.html#absurd-patterns) to match an instance of a type with no constructors, and when it matches, we skip writing the case body entirely ([example derived from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42288848)).

```
open import Data.List
open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Unit
open import Data.Empty

isNonEmpty {A : Set} → (xs : List A) → Prop
isNonEmpty [] = ⊥
isNonEmpty (x ∷ xs) = ⊤

-- The second argument is a predicate that can only has an instance when the
-- list is nonempty, so we don't need to return anything from the first case
head : {A : Set} → (xs : List A) → (nonEmpty : IsNonEmpty xs) → A
head [] () -- `()` is the absurd pattern. Since `IsNonEmpty [] = ⊥` and no
           -- instances of `⊥` exist, it matches.
head (x ∷ xs) _ = x
```

---

But (you may already know) the best solution is usually to turn your pattern-matching statement into something which doesn't have predicates, only constructors. The downside is that this can be non-straightforward and sometimes impossible to do safely (see: undecidable problems), but when it's practical, you don't need a theorem-proving language to prove exhaustiveness. For instance, instead of something like:

```ocaml
let handle_packet p :=
  if is_connect p then
    handle_connect (connect_data p)
  else if is_disconnect p then
    handle_disconnect (disconnect_data p)
  else if is_data_packet f then
    handle_data_packet (packet_data p)
  else
    error "unreachable!"
  ;;
```

you'd want to use

````ocaml
type packet := Connect connect_data | Disconnect disconnect_data | Data bytes

let parse_packet p : packet := ...

let handle_packet p 
  match (parse_packet p) with
  | Connect data -> handle_connect data
  | Disconnect data -> handle_disconnect data
  | Data data -> handle_data_packet data
  ;;
```
````

Comment: Originally I think the undecidable will have 3 cases, true, false, and unknown. I think there has a problem, but I didn't what it is, thanks! I think absurd pattern is a proper answer.